# Callback function when clicked on "selected date" in daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, daterangepicker

using the latest version of [Daterangepicker for bootstrap](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#options)

For the following calendar (standard example used in their website):

```
$('#demo').daterangepicker({
    "singleDatePicker": true,
    "autoApply": true,
    "startDate": "05/31/2017",
    "endDate": "06/06/2017"
}, function(start, end, label) {
  console.log("a date is selected")
});
```

The given callback function is called correctly when I select a date in my calendar. However, if I select the active date which is already selected, the pop up is closed but the callback function is not called. As far as I see, there is no any opportunity provided to fire a function when the same date is selected.

So, my question would be: Is there a hacking way to have a callback function which is called when the same date is selected?

For instance, I tried the following piece of code to add a listener to the active cell but it is also not fired:

```
 $('td.active.start-date.active.end-date.available').on('click', function () {
   console.log('the same date is selected')
 })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is bind an extra event to your input which will be called when you select an option. See the following code (assuming the element with id demo is your input) Since you already use jQuery my example uses this as well:

```
$('#demo').on('change.datepicker', function(ev){
  var picker = $(ev.target).data('daterangepicker');
  console.log(picker.startDate); // contains the selected start date
  console.log(picker.endDate); // contains the selected end date 

  // ... here you can compare the dates and call your callback.
});
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: I wonder how that event will be called? Is `change.datepicker` a standard event of daterangepicker or should I define it somewhere on which event it will be called? Instead of that, I used a `click` event but it didn't do the trick

Comment: While `hover`, `mouseenter`, `mouseleave` etc are working, `click` is not working at all. What can be the reason?

Comment: On which type of control do you bind the daterangepicker? On a regular input type="text"? Can you post the html u are using or setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: The change.datepicker is a standard event from the daterangepicker, which will be triggered on the bound element, when you bind another handling to that event like in my example you just add another listener to the already present event.

Comment: when you open the url in your question and run the following line of code directly in your chrome devtools console and pick a range and apply you will see the both dates logged in the console:
$('#config-demo').on('change.datepicker', function(ev){ var picker = $(ev.target).data('daterangepicker'); console.log(picker.startDate); console.log(picker.endDate); });

Comment: see the following jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mpjzpnyq/ I was using a font-awesome icon so that might be the problem that your solution didn't work at me I think?

Comment: I have updated your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mpjzpnyq/2/ because of the font awesome icon you don't have an input which usualluy contains the selected date. (If you have a regular form you need to consider putting in actual form elements, for posting). So I have added a hidden input which you can bind the datepickerrange on and delegate any click on the span (fontawesome icon) to trigger the click on the datepickerrange. This will popup the date picker. The rest will be handled accordingly. If you open the dev tools in the fiddle you will see the console.logs present.

Comment: It has solved this issue. However, I got now other issues related to my project. Can you provide any documentation/or any way to get know about standard events of daterangepicker? Another event could solve my other issues, I hope.

Comment: The official events are documented here: http://www.daterangepicker.com/#events Besides that I looked into the javascript as well: http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js search for the "event listeners" and you will several other events which can be used such as the: "change.daterangepicker". Glad I could be of any help!

Answer (score 1):

The 'click' event does not work, but the 'mousedown' event does.

Below an example, which identifies the clicked element ('td.available') and programatically clicks the same date again.

```
$('#demo').on('showCalendar.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {

    function triggerMouseEvent (node, eventType) {
        var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
        clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true);
        node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
    }
    // when user selects ("mousedown") any date in the calendar:
    $('td.available').on("mousedown", function() {
        clickedElement = $('td.in-range')[0]; // this is the clicked element
        
        // example: programatically click again.
        triggerMouseEvent (clickedElement, "mouseover");
        triggerMouseEvent (clickedElement, "mousedown");
        triggerMouseEvent (clickedElement, "mouseup");
        triggerMouseEvent (clickedElement, "click");
      );
    });
});
```

Comment: mousedown did the trick - thanks for that hint!